# How can I automatically add conditions in the method of a resource controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-resource

I am trying to add a `if` condition when resource auto generates.

When I run `php artisan make:controller SomeController -r`, I want to generate the following,

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
        }else{
           //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might have to look into custom generators so you can define the stub file you want to use to generate the controller ... if you actually want a custom controller made like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the above, go to terminal and

- run `php artisan stub:publish`
- Check the root directory for `stubs` directory.
- Modify the `controller.stub` according to you need and it's done!

When you run `php artisan make:controller -r` the next time, it will autogenerate the resource with the changes you made to the `stub` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use middleware to do this,
See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;

class AuthCan {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('')){
           //
           return $next($request);
        }else{
           //
           return response()->json(['status' => false, 'code' => 1001, 'msg' => 'Cannot ...']);
        }

    }
}
```

Defined your route Middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'AuthCan' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthCan::class,
    ...
```

And use middleware in route.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'AuthCan'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'SomeController@index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'SomeController@show');
    ...
}
```